# Unexpected Error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String DecryptValue(Byte[], System.String)' method

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

My udf:

```
[EdmFunction("Model.Store", "Decrypt")]
public static string Decrypt(byte[] Value, string Passphrase)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

My LINQ call:

```
var passphrase = "phrase123";
var decryptedValue = (from p in unitOfWork.context.Values
                      where p.ValueID== valueId
                      select Decrypt(p.value, passphrase)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is the actual error message:

> Unexpected Error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Decrypt(Byte[], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

SQL function

```
CREATE FUNCTION DB.Decrypt
(
    @Value VARBINARY(200),
    @Passphrase varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
```

How do i fix this in order to decrypt the value?  Thanks

**UPDATE**:
I changed my edmfunction to try to handle the varbinary to this:

```
public static string Decrypt(SqlBinary Value, string Passphrase)
```

And got a new error message of this:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Decrypt(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Which still leads me to believe something is wrong with the varbinary equvialent in C#

Comment: You are trying to use code in an expression that will not translate to sql. Just return the value first and then decrypt it.

Comment: @StephenBrickner the decrypt function is implemented on SQL server; it's just not being 'connected' with the c# version.

Comment: Can you run the decrypt function correctly by an equivalent SELECT statement in Management Studio? Can you post a successfully-executing query?

Comment: Did you forgot to import the function into your db model?

Comment: The function is in the db model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was so simple.  My EdmFunction was using the wrong reference due to resharper's advice....  the correct class to be using is

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

Sorry for bringing the headache to you all, thanks for all of your efforts!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Linq to Entities is trying to expand to something like;

```
select Decrypt(p.Value, @passphrase) 
from values p
where p.valueid = @valueId
```

and it seems to be having trouble matching your code's Decrypt function with the matching one on the server. It looks ok, from other examples I've seen, so I suspect it's a minor 'glue' issue...

I wonder if any of these might be useful leads;

- C# Decrypt() takes a byte[] as the first parameter -- is that the actual datatype of p.value? If it's a string, for instance, you might need to nudge the types in the function declaration.
- Have you definitely got the function on the database you're currently connecting to? Maybe missing some kind of update?

Comment: Hi Steve, the actual datatype for p.value is varbinary. I did some  research to find the c#equivalent is byte[]. I definitely have the function though, And it hasn't changed.

Comment: Can you execute it as a plain SQL statement in SSMS? If so, then it will be something in the EDMX; I read the basic error as meaning 'Linq to Entities doesn't know Decrypt(byte[], string) so your use of it is illegal.' Must be something small like a schema name, parameter name typo, something like that. Is uow.context.Values a plain IDbSet<T>?

Comment: Yes it is, and it's the table that houses the valueid and p.value

Comment: I'm struggling to see anything wrong with your code, really. Could you maybe post a few more bits of code on your original question? Maybe the 'outer' parts of your CREATE FUNCTION statement -- not the body, but the part with names, parameter names, parameter types, etc. Also, is "Model.Store" the right namespace? If the namespace was off, it might exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: Added function outer parts in post.  Also, I renamed what im actually using in my project to Model.Store.  But I just verified it to be correct.  I edited the EDMX file in xml to make sure of it.

Comment: I personally feel like it has something to do with my edmfunction